# Probability: Possible values of $X$

Tags: probability

This is a problem from Ross' "A first course in Probability".

Let $X$ represent the difference between the number of heads and the number of tails obtained when a coin is tossed $n$ times. What are the possible values of $X$?

My answer is all even's from -n to n for n is even (inclusive). If n is odd, then all the odds from -n to n (inclusive).

The provided answer in the book is n-2i; i = 0, ..., n

Why would they ignore the fact that n can be odd or even? Or does it not matter and I am complicating myself?

Comment: It is considering the parity! Notice that the parity of $n-2i$ is the same as $n$ since we are subtracting an even number ($2i$)

Comment: Oh... Should have plugged in before asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is all the evens between $-n$ and $n$ when $n$ is even, and all the odds between $-n$ and $n$ when $n$ is odd.

That is  $\{-n, 2-n,\ldots, n-2, n\}$ when $n$ is even, and $\{-n, 2-n, \ldots, n-2, n\}$ when $n$ is odd.

Which means, whether $n$ is even or odd , that it is $\{-n, 2-n, \ldots, n-2, n\}$.

This is also $\{n-2i: i\in \{0,1,\ldots, n\}\}$, as per the given answer.